# Dynamically generate content on application server for downoloading

Tags: jakarta-ee, download, javabeans, web

I use application server, e.g. geronimo, to run some EAR/WAR applications.
And now I need some kind of data transfer service, but the data is so large that it may not be suitable to be transferred via JMS/Queue which my application bases on.

One idea is that the service generates the content and stores it on the file system of application server. Then the client can retrieve the content with HTTP download.

The question is how can I store something from a Java EE MDB Bean onto file system which is accessible with HTTP link. Or any alternative solution?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you store the data on the local disk file system, then there are basically 2 ways to provide it by HTTP:

1. Create an extra webapp context pointing to the root local disk file system location. I have no idea how to do it in Gernimo, but in Tomcat for example it's a matter of adding the following entry to `/conf/server.xml`

   ```
   <Context path="/files" docBase="/absolute/path/to/files" />
   ```

   This way it's available by http://example.com/files/whatever.ext
2. Create a servlet which gets a `FileInputStream` from the disk and writes it to `OutputStream` of the response, along with a set of proper response headers. Then invoke the servlet by its URL with the filename as request path or parameter.